# Error Message: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme with this activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

This question has been asked so many times, but still i am unable to solve this problem.

I am trying to show Alert windows in my activity. Its giving me following error message

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity

This is my code.

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

        btnCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(cbApprove.isChecked()){

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Thanks");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Thanks for participating in ticketing flow. The test ends here for the Beta");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();

                }
            }
        });
```

**Manifest File**

```
<activity
    android:name=".ticketing.activities.CartActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_cart"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

    ></activity>
```

**Style v21**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I have also changed the style of layout to AppComat.NoActionBar`from Layout Design`.

**Error Message**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.tixsee.mavs, PID: 15867
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:340)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:273)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:80)
 at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)
 at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:256)
 at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:463)
 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
 at com.tixsee.mavs.ticketing.activities.CartActivity$1.onClick(CartActivity.java:92)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
```

Comment: go in mainfest and change activity theme

Comment: Please post your entire stack trace.

Comment: which activity u have got error change like that  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

Comment: Yes its only for lollipop and higher version, @Kishanpatel i have  changed activity theme from layout design.

Comment: Visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940291/4832664) for solving to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the error is caused because of using AlertDialog in your code. You need to pass your activity's context instead of the application context to the alertdialog builder. Get the context in your `AlertDialog Builder` using `getActivity()` instead of using `getApplicationContext()`. Like this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
```

Comment: Thank you, This solved my problem. I wrote following code .

   AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CartActivity.this).create();

Answer (score 1):

Use the following theme in your style

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFC107</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">#4CAF50</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```