# How to fix: "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"

Tags: android, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I am having trouble running my Android app in a fullscreen mode per instructions of a video. When it tries to run, the app crashes with the error.

`"You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity`

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.djsg38.hikerswatch">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Styles File

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Partial MainActivity that may be useful

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Your application has an AppCompat theme

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

But, you overwrote the Activity (which extends AppCompatActivity) with a theme that isn't descendant of an AppCompat theme

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

You could define your own fullscreen theme like so (notice **`AppCompat`** in the `parent=`)

```
<style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Then set that on the Activity.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme" >
```

**Note**: There might be an AppCompat theme that's already full screen, but don't know immediately

Comment: I will try this, although, it does like very similar to something I have tried. Sorry, I should've posted a chunk of code where I didn't use "Theme.NoTitleBar..."

Comment: I just want to state that I had to remove the "android:theme=@style/AppFullScreenTheme" from under the Activity section. With it there, it caused breakage of the app due to activity not assignable.

Comment: What do you mean "not assignable"? You had to add the `AppFullScreenTheme` style in the `styles.xml`, then you could use that in the Manifest as written

Comment: The video I followed told me to add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ` under the `<activity` section, which gave "Activity is not assignable to Activity" error; yet, the guy in the video did not receive errors.

Comment: Was he extending `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: He was extending `Activity`, as he was using a much older version of AS, while I did extend `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Version of Android Studio shouldn't matter. You got an error because you were extending `AppCompatActivity`, which requires an `AppCompat` theme. The video was not getting an error because it used regular `Activity`, which does not need those themes.

Comment: Ahh..no other answers seemed to describe that issue clearly, which left me very confused for a long time. Thank you for the help, and I just marked it - sorry, had to figure out how.

Answer (score 45):

Used to face the same problem. The reason was in incorrect context passing to `AlertDialog.Builder(here)`. use like
AlertDialog.Builder(Homeactivity.this)

Comment: Uhhh, this was for me as well. I was passing in the App context instead of the Activity context. Error message does not indicate this is the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I was using dialogbox on onClickListener and was passing the incorrect context.

Comment: I have the same reason but I'm passing the right context. Can't solve the problem

Comment: Try another approach - use fragment context in MaterialAlertDialog from the material library. 


val dialog = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
                .setView(customLayout)
                .show()

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It's strange the getContextApplication() wasn't working neither the keyword(this), but with the class worked without problem.

Comment: Tahnks a lot, you saved my day! I faced the same issue and that was the main reason for my crash.

Answer (score 10):

You should add a `theme` to your all activities (You should add `theme` for all application in your `<application>` in your manifest)
but if you have set different theme to your activity you can use :

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

or each kind of `AppCompat` theme!

Answer (score 5):

If you add the `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to `<application>` in AndroidManifest.xml file, problem is solving.

Comment: This answer is particularly useful for Flutter projects

Answer (score 3):

Note that there may be 2 `styles.xml` in `/values/` and `/values-night/`, in your project, for when the OS setting is set to Light or Dark mode. In both you need to replace the default Theme with an `AppCompat` Theme in case you have the Dark setting on. Sometimes is only ON at night, so your app may compile during the day but stop working after certain hour, causing a lot of debugging confusion and headache. This also causes it to fail only in some devices (sim vs real for example):

old

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

new

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 2):

This Error comes, when you use a **AlertDialog** in an activity. If you want get solution of this problem, you just need to make sure that in which activity you wanted to show the **AlertDialog** popup, this context must be like **Demo.this**. never use the **getApplicationContext**.

Comment: Gotcha! plus one

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error while trying to setup **react-native-bootsplash**, in their documentation they say you have to change you application theme from this

```
<application
     ...
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

to this

```
<application
      ...
      android:theme="@style/BootTheme">
```

But what worked for me was to leave the application theme as `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` and change the **activity** theme, like that:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/BootTheme"/> <!-- HERE -->
```

**Entire AndroidManifest.xml file**

````
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.rv_supplier"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- It's necessary because of react-native-qrcode-scanner -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

      <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/BootTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/notification_ic"
        tools:replace="android:resource" />
    </application>
</manifest>

```
````

Comment: can you please add the full manifest file?

Comment: @Andrey ok, I updated the answer with the file

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue.
If your application is using Theme.MaterialComponents......
then other place if using @android:style/Theme.... then this issue faced.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by the below:
 
I added the below and it fixed the problem for me
 
 - In this file: **build.gradle.kts** (module :app) add:
 
   
implementation("androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.6")