# Unable to resolve error Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)

Tags: android

I looked at other SO posts and configured accordingly. But I still see this issue on some Android devices (4.3.1). It works 75% of time.

`You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

What is wrong with code below?

```
BaseActivity extends android.support.v7.appAppCompatActivity



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

All activities (crashed acitivity as well) use AppTheme from application tag. One activity uses:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.EntryActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
```

I don't have any other style.xml.

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
</style>
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

From Android:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

---

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{Activities.MyAcitivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity. 1   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>   2 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>   3 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   4 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   5 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 6    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 7 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 8   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 9    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 10   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   11    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   12    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Native Method) 13    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 14  Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity. 15  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.i(SourceFile:340) 16   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.h(SourceFile:309) 17   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(SourceFile:273)
>   18    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:136)
>   19    at .Commons.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:236) 20    at
>   .MyActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:24) 21    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 22 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   23    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>   24    ... 12 more 25  java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a
>   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. 26  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.i(SourceFile:340) 27   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.h(SourceFile:309) 28   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(SourceFile:273)
>   29    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(SourceFile:136)
>   30    at Activities.Commons.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:236) 31  at
>   Activities.Accounts.AppLaunchActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:24) 32  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 33 at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   34    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>   35    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>   36    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   37    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   38    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 39   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 40    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 41  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 42   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 43   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   44    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   45    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Native Method) 46    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Just post the complete crash log.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">   //base Application theme
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.EntryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">   //Activity Theme
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I don't need Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. Then why do I need to add it to style.xml?

Comment: it  really doesn't matter...you are not using the `DarkActionBar` if u set the theme to be `AppTheme.NoActionBar`..if u don;t want it u can use `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` as ur applicaiton theme..see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604889/how-to-fix-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-a