# Android "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-theme

Ok , im getting this error (title) .
Many post suggested me (even Android studio) to change the theme , to App.Appcompat , i have done it .

Manifest file :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ContactAcitivty"
        android:label="@string/activity_title_contact" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CopyrightActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_title_copyright" />
    <activity android:name=".activity.FormActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.FormActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

</application>
```

Style.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"  parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

BUT still , nothing changed .

I don't know what happened since i didn't had this problem before (i didn't add App.compat in the manifest file bfore)

Gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

The Error log :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme     (or descendant) with the design library.    
at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)     
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init> (NavigationView.java:102)   
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:96)   
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)           

at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)  
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)      
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)  
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: post the full manifest...

Comment: why are you using the beta version of support library?

Comment: Ok i edited my post . Im just following a tutorial about naviguation drawer from , this one http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ , so i used the beta version as explained in the tutorial

Comment: '24.0.0-beta1' is old and beta version. Current stable version is '25.2.0'

Comment: ok i will change the version , and tell you if that resolve my problem

Comment: Is it the dependency order that was causing error?

Comment: Visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45940291/4832664) for solving to your problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this changes:

in gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

Also in manifest add the `appcompat` theme to your Navaigation drawer `Activity

```
<activity android:name=".activity.FormActivity"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.FormActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `MainActivity` is using `@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar` theme, and it's not a descendant of `Theme.AppCompat`

Change

`<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">`

to

`<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using constraint layout, make sure that you are using the version greater than or equal to 1.1.3. I was getting this error when I was using the version 1.0.2