# App unexpectedly crashing

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, theming

My application is crashing when I sign in. The  log cat shows this: `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

I tried to show my menu in Navigation Drawer acctivity, then used the same activity on the client side and it worked, but server side it's keeping crashing  after I sign in.

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    TextView txtFullName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); //(Home.java:27)

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Menu Management");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Set name for user
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtFullName = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
    txtFullName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

My style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="CollapsedAppbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

My style v21

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>



<style name="ExpendedAppbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

My manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".SignIn"></activity>
</application>
```

My log cat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mohamed.myapplicationserveur/com.example.mohamed.myapplicationserveur.Home}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:354)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                  at com.example.mohamed.myapplicationserveur.Home.onCreate(Home.java:27)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/5374691

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604889/how-to-fix-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-a/39604946

Comment: Sorry i'm new with programmation, i didn't understand those solution can you please help me ?