# Android Studio getActionBar() returns null?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im following this 5 year old Android course on Udemy, and trying to make this app work on the current Android Studio version, i've so far been able to figure out how to at least make it build, but now when I try running the app on Genymotion it doesn't run the first time, and when i run the second time i get this:

[image]

and I get this in the "logcat" tab:

```
2020-07-08 22:41:34.665 2198-2198/? I/Zygote: seccomp disabled by setenforce 0
2020-07-08 22:41:34.666 2198-2198/? I/lta_bartalk_ne: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-07-08 22:41:34.690 2198-2198/? W/lta_bartalk_ne: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-07-08 22:41:34.814 2198-2223/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2020-07-08 22:41:34.809 2198-2198/com.example.delta_bartalk_new I/com.example.delta_bartalk_new: type=1400 audit(0.0:670): avc: denied { write } for comm=45474C20496E6974 name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=10316 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c70,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=1
2020-07-08 22:41:34.809 2198-2198/com.example.delta_bartalk_new I/com.example.delta_bartalk_new: type=1400 audit(0.0:671): avc: denied { connectto } for comm=45474C20496E6974 path="/dev/socket/property_service" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c70,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
2020-07-08 22:41:34.815 2198-2223/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-07-08 22:41:34.818 2198-2223/com.example.delta_bartalk_new E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
2020-07-08 22:41:34.818 2198-2223/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-07-08 22:41:34.841 2198-2223/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-07-08 22:41:34.842 2198-2223/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-07-08 22:41:34.856 2198-2223/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-07-08 22:41:34.866 2198-2198/com.example.delta_bartalk_new W/lta_bartalk_ne: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
2020-07-08 22:41:34.889 2198-2223/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-07-08 22:41:34.891 2198-2223/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-07-08 22:41:34.894 2198-2198/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-07-08 22:41:34.895 2198-2198/com.example.delta_bartalk_new E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.delta_bartalk_new, PID: 2198
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.delta_bartalk_new/com.delta.bartalk_new.BartalkActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
        at com.delta.bartalk_new.BartalkActivity.onCreate(BartalkActivity.java:81)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

And here is the **BartalkActivity.java** file:

```
package com.delta.bartalk_new;

import com.delta.bartalk_new.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */

public class BartalkActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    //
// Bartalk instance variables
//
    TextView mOutputText;
    EditText mInputText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bartalk);

//
// Bartalk code
//
        mOutputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        mInputText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);

        mInputText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                mOutputText.setText(mInputText.getText());
            }
        });

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

// Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
// this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
// If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
// (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
// in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
// screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView.animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
// If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren’t
// available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
// controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
// Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

// Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

// Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
// operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
// while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.input_text).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
// created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
// are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }


    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }

            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

I noticed that when I just comment out the `getActionBar()` bit, then it actually does run, but i assume something does not get "hidden" while using the app.

I've been looking at this whole "getActionBar() returning null" issue, and I keep seeing a bunch of answers, but none of them seem to be working. The most promising one of using `getSupportActionBar()` doesn't even work since when i try to build it Android Studio complains it can't find that method.

What would i need to do to get this `getActionBar()` method working...?

**Update 01**
So following [Gabriele Mariotti's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) advice, I changed the import statements to use AppCompatActivity(didn't really know how to add the v7 Support Libraries even after reading the doc linked by [Jaiprakash Soni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567776/jaiprakash-soni)). this is what the **BartalkActivity.java** file looks like now:

```
package com.delta.bartalk_new;

import com.delta.bartalk_new.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
//import android.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
//import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */

public class BartalkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    //
// Bartalk instance variables
//
    TextView mOutputText;
    EditText mInputText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bartalk);

//
// Bartalk code
//
        mOutputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        mInputText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);

        mInputText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                mOutputText.setText(mInputText.getText());
            }
        });

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

// Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
// this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
                .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
// If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
// (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
// in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
// screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView.animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
// If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren’t
// available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
// controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
// Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

// Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

// Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
// operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
// while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.input_text).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
// created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
// are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }


    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }

            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

but now it gives me the same *"keeps stopping"* error, but getting a different error in the logcat:

```
2020-07-09 10:35:50.719 2135-2135/? I/Zygote: seccomp disabled by setenforce 0
2020-07-09 10:35:50.721 2135-2135/? I/lta_bartalk_ne: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-07-09 10:35:50.751 2135-2135/? W/lta_bartalk_ne: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-07-09 10:35:50.912 2135-2160/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2020-07-09 10:35:50.909 2135-2135/com.example.delta_bartalk_new I/com.example.delta_bartalk_new: type=1400 audit(0.0:718): avc: denied { write } for comm=45474C20496E6974 name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=9292 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c70,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=1
2020-07-09 10:35:50.915 2135-2160/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-07-09 10:35:50.921 2135-2160/com.example.delta_bartalk_new E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
2020-07-09 10:35:50.921 2135-2160/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-07-09 10:35:50.943 2135-2160/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-07-09 10:35:50.944 2135-2160/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-07-09 10:35:50.950 2135-2160/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-07-09 10:35:50.982 2135-2135/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-07-09 10:35:50.985 2135-2135/com.example.delta_bartalk_new E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.delta_bartalk_new, PID: 2135
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.delta_bartalk_new/com.delta.bartalk_new.BartalkActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.delta.bartalk_new.BartalkActivity.onCreate(BartalkActivity.java:66)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-07-09 10:35:50.992 2135-2160/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
2020-07-09 10:35:50.994 2135-2160/com.example.delta_bartalk_new D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
```

so now its complaining about `setContentView(R.layout.activity_bartalk);`. why is this?

Comment: `Im following this 5 year old Android course on Udemy` - Don't do that.

Comment: Android changed a bit in the last 5 years. You can start changing the `Activity` in `AppCompatActivity` and then you can use `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: Follow this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up#java

Answer (score 0):

After examining the logcat output more carefully, i noticed something about AppCompat theme, looked it up further, and found this ticket:
[How to fix: "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604889/how-to-fix-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-a/39604946)

After following this, and adding my own text colors in values/colors.xml, i was able to make this load correctly in Genymotion. thank you to [Gabriele Mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) for providing me the hint to using `AppCompatActivity`.