# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

I programmed a navigationDrawer and created a new style for it, then put a recyclerView inside a fragment now I get this error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myfood.app/com.myfood.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Without the recyclerView everything works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

styles.xml(v21):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyFood.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

themes.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyFood" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#72CC86</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyFood.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myfood.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyFood">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyFood.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope somebody can help me out with this problem.

Comment: So where do you apply that theme to your activity? Please include your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity) or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604889/how-to-fix-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-a)

Comment: Did you at any point use `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()` to inflate layouts or create views? That would be a problem.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I only used getContext()

Comment: @ianhanniballake I edited my post so you can see the Manifest.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace